# Laplace's equation periodic in one dimension, from boundary values

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve Laplace's equation in a domain that is semin infinite in one ordinate and periodic in the other.

That is, we consider a pair of functions $x(\xi,\nu),y(\xi,\nu)$ such that we have the information 
$$f(\xi) = x(\xi,0)+i y(\xi,0),$$
where $f(\xi)$ is the boundary value of the analytic function $F(\xi,\nu)$. The domain is such that $\xi \in (0,2\pi)$ while $\nu \in (-\infty,0)$.

I would like to find $x(\xi,\nu)$ and $y(\xi,\nu)$, that is, the analytic extension of these functions to the semi infinite strip.

Any tips, or suggestions, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's not very clear what is actually known: is the function $F$ known? Also, you talk about "the domain" (half-infinite strip), and also about lower halfplane. In what domain is the equation posed? Anyway, one option is to subtract a constant from the boundary data so that it average is zero. Then the [Poisson integral for halfplane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel#On_the_upper_half-plane) will likely converge.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. Thanks for the reply. The function $f(\xi)$ is given, that is, we know the value of the function $F$ on the line $\nu=0$. The domain is $\xi \in (0,2\pi)$ and $\nu \in (-\infty,0)$. I will modify the question appropriately. I have seen the solution for this when $\xi \in (-\infty,\infty)$, which would be the lower half plane. However, I'm confused as to how this changes when I assume $(x,y)$ are $2\pi$ periodic.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the approach depends on what the given function is. Some functions are easier to integrate against the Poisson kernel than others. Also, some functions can be related to a holomorphic function  in an algebraic way.

To use the Poisson kernel:

1. Subtract the mean value from the given boundary function $x$. You can add it to $x$ later.
2. Extend $x$ by periodicity, i.e., make it a $2\pi$-periodic function on $\mathbb R$.
3. Convolve with the [Poisson kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel#On_the_upper_half-plane) 
   $$x(\xi,\nu) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{-\nu}{(\xi-t)^2+\nu^2} x(t)\,dt $$
   and the conjugate Poisson kernel
   $$y(\xi,\nu) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{ t-\xi  }{(\xi-t)^2+\nu^2} x(t)\,dt $$

The integrals should converge (the second only conditionally, and that only thanks to removing the mean value  of $x$). Whether or not you can actually evaluate them is anyone's guess.